# Como converter um JSON em uma classe genérica

Tags: java, json, genéricos

Em um projeto com várias aplicações cliente-servidor, tenho uma série de arquivos de configuração em JSON, que contêm a porta de conexão, host, etc. Para cada aplicação, as informações constantes no JSON são diferentes:

configCache.json

```
{
    "port": "1234",
    "managerServerHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "managerServerPort": "1235",
    "cacheTimeout": "10000"
}
```

configSGBD.json

```
{
    "port": "1235",
    "studentServerHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "studentServerPort": "1236",
    "classServerHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "classServerPort": "1237"
}
```

configAlunos.json

```
{
   "port":"1236",
   "datafile":"student.data"
}
```

Ao rodar essas aplicações, preciso pegar estas informações do JSON de configuração de cada uma para setar porta do Socket, etc. Me sugeriram usar uma única classe genérica para converter cada JSON e pegar as informações que preciso em cada aplicação. Mas não entendi muito bem como funcionam as classes genéricas e como usá-la no meu problema. Alguém disposto a ajudar??

Comment: Não vejo em que uma classe genérica ajudaria nesse caso. Sugiro criar um `JSONObject` a partir da string com a biblioteca [org.json](https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-java-o-pacote-org-json/25480) e ler os dados desse objeto ou fazer algo semelhante com a biblioteca Jackson, que é mais atual.

Comment: Sobre classes genéricas, tratam-se de classes parametrizadas com um tipo adicional, por exemplo a classe genérica `ArrayList<Integer>` armazena inteiros ao passo que a classe `ArrayList<String>` armazena strings. Pesquise sobre classes genéticas no Java para se informar melhor, mas veja que não há muito sentido em usá-las aqui.